# Change the default colors of a mosaic plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, mosaic-plot

I want to change the color of this mosaic plot to make it printable in black in white but can't find a way to change this parameter

[image: the mosaic plot]

```
from statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot import mosaic
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas

x = ['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes']
y = ['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no']
data = pandas.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
mosaic(data, ['x', 'y'])

plt.savefig("mosaicplot.pdf", figsize=[10,5])
plt.show()
```

Here is what I actually have : I saw I could change the color with mosaic(properties) on this link : http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot.mosaic.html
but I can only give 2 different colors and I need a different color for each plot, like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you show what you expect the figure to loop like?

Comment: the function returns the rectangles. You will need to colorize them yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot.mosaic.html) mentions a `properties=` argument:

> **properties    function (key) -> dict, optional**
>
> A function that for each tile in the mosaic take the key of the tile and returns the dictionary of properties of the generated
>   Rectangle, like color, hatch or similar. A default properties set will
>   be provided fot the keys whose color has not been defined, and will
>   use color variation to help visually separates the various categories.
>   It should return None to indicate that it should use the default
>   property for the tile. A dictionary of the properties for each key can
>   be passed, and it will be internally converted to the correct function

Therefore, you can pass either a function (see the example in the link above), or more simply a dictionary, to `properties=` to change the appearance of the rectangles:

```
x = ['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes']
y = ['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no']
data = pandas.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})

props = {}
props[('yes', 'yes')] = {'color': 'xkcd:orange'}
props[('yes','no')] = {'facecolor': 'xkcd:pale blue',
                       'edgecolor':'xkcd:light grey',
                       'hatch':'o'}
data = pandas.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
mosaic(data, ['x', 'y'], properties=props)
```

[image]

As far as I can tell, [any argument accepted by `Rectangle`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html?highlight=rectangle#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle) can be passed along in this dictionary.